# JavaScript: How to perfectly time a function

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

i hope you can help me with this.
I´m writing on my bachelor thesis at the moment and came to a point where i don´t know how to move on. so here is my question:
i´ve got a function in a given code that is called every 100ms. In this function i wrote another function that plays an audio record and it should be called only once in 10 seconds and i really do not know how to realize it.
I tried it with an additional counter (see code below) but it doesn´t work like it´s supposed to..

```
if(fall_detected == true && counter == 0)
{
   counter++;
   var exec = require('child_process').exec;
   function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(stdout) }
   exec("aplay /home/test.wav", puts);  
}
```

I tried it with a timeout after the exex-line but it doesn´t work..
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be complete. What have you tried so far? You can use `setInterval()` to repeatedly call a function after time has passed.

Comment: Your counter never resets after 10s.